# In Robot Framework, which is better to create custom library java or python

Tags: robotframework

I know java language very well, i created custom library in java.
while executing i am using `jybot` to execute the scripts.

When i am running the scripts have Oracle Database Connection, got few errors like `cx_oracle is not found`, but i ran the same script with `pybot` option i got no errors.

I understood that when i execute the script using jybot, the verification of folders for prerequisites is different.

I want to know, which is better or have more functions to create our custom library java or python.

I want to know the difference between `jybot` and `pybot` when it comes to the execution of scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three questions you are asking: 
1. What is the difference between pybot (python) and robot on Jython.
2. What is the better approach for developing custom libraries.
3. What causes my Oracle problems.

For question 1 the answer is that in principle the same core code is running for robot running on Python as well as within Jython. So in that sense this shouldn't matter much. However, as most people are running the pure Python flavour this version would probably be the better version from a support perspective. That said, if you and your colleagues are more comfortable with Java, then this may be the better option for you.

Regarding question 2. This follows the same line as the answer for 1. If you feel more comfortable with Java, then this should be fine. However, since robot at the core is a Python application (even on Jython) it makes more sense to run this version. This has also been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538919/how-to-implement-a-java-library-in-robot-framework) and a tutorial about the [Remote Library](http://blog.xebia.com/the-robot-framework-remote-library-interface-using-the-remote-database-library-to-connect-to-ibm-db2/) approach also good to read. In any case the [official documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-robot-framework) holds great examples as well.

For your last question. Please provide us with more details, or better yet; create a new question for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kootstra, i will create separate question for oracle issue.