# Stuck with creating Keyword library using Java in Eclipse and using that JAR file in RIDE

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to ROBOT framework and must create library keyword using java and utilize the JAR files in RIDE editor. I have followed the below steps. But still have confusions in where to start up. Please help me to achieve this.

Steps:

```
1) Installed Python, wxPython, pybot, RIDE, selenium2library successfully and I'm able to work with RIDE using predefined keywords.
2) For creating own java library, Installed Eclipse Mars, Java, ROBOT IDE manually using the link https://github.com/NitorCreations/RobotFramework-EclipseIDE/wiki/Installation
```

The question here is,
    Anything i'm missing to install?
    How to proceed further with Robot Framework coding?

Note: I'm reading many materials in parts to proceed things. But that is confusing me what are the steps to be followed. Is there any single material that i can get having the sequences of steps that need to be followed for my requirements?

The below links I referred with,

- https://github.com/NitorCreations/RobotFramework-EclipseIDE/wiki/Usage
- [Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)
- [Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype)
- http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the basics. RIDE is an editor for Robot Script files. Robot Script files are executed by the Robot Framework robot application. It is important to understand the difference between these two applications. One creates files and the other uses them.

Assuming for a moment here that you have some custom functionality in a Jar file that you would like to make available inside the Robot Script files test cases. If this is indeed the case then your focus should be on create [Robot Test Libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries). In the documentation there are numerous java examples given for basing your own library on.

This means that you do not need Maven, unless you want to, to create your library. Also Eclipse IDE is not needed nor is RIDE. The library you create can be used by Robot Framework even when it's run from the command line. Feel free to use them for what they are good at: writing Robot Scripts efficiently and running Robot through menu options instead of command line windows.

When you are familiar with Eclipse and comfortable with it's features, then I can also recommend using the Eclipse Application [RED](https://github.com/nokia/RED) which is a mature Eclipse add on for creating, running and debugging Robot scripts.

There are two ways of implementing a Java routine in Robot Framework and it depends a bit on how you run Robot Framework: Python or Jython.  Running Python means that you need to run the Java in a separate JVM container and connect to it. The simplest way is via Command Line interaction. This may cause some security concerns. The second approach is to use the Remote Library approach. A good example of this is the Robot Framework [Sikuli Library](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary). An added bonus is that you can run Robot and your Java application on two separate machines/servers.

The Jython way has been discussed on StackOverflow [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538919/how-to-implement-a-java-library-in-robot-framework) and I gladly refer to it. Please bear in mind that although the examples refer to RIDE, the `Library    org.company.Keywordlibrary`  works in all IDE's, provided robot framework is run using Jython.

In the [Jython documentation](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html) it clearly explains how to setup an Eclipse based IDE with Jython. Do keep in mind that it's recommended to use the same interpreter in development and production. I.e. if you create your scripts in Jython, do run them in 'production' also using Jython. Otherwise you open yourself up to interpreter differences where functionality does not work or behaves differently then expected.

An alternative approach with Jython is the all-in-one [Robot Framework Maven JAR plugin](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#standalone-jar-distribution). Adding a custom Java Library in this setup is not too difficult. A nice short tutorial can be found on the blog of [Valerio Bruno](http://www.valeriobruno.it/blog3/2013/04/28/writing-acceptance-test-with-robot-framework-in-java/). If this is your preferred route for development, then you may want to read the RED howto on [integrating the Robot Framework Maven jar](https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/9d62dccce18ee7f3051162d05bf3d027e33dccef/red_help/user_guide/maven.html.md).

Working on your custom functionality is likely going to be a independent project in Eclipse, but can be linked to an Robot project via the Class Path settings in red.xml if you use RED or the CLASS_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kootstra! This gives me clarity to proceed further. Since I'm familiar with Eclipse and my management prefers to work with Java, I would choose RED as a base for creating libraries. Thanks again!

Comment: You're more than welcome. Can you mark this as the correct answer? This helps those that search for answers better to know that this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Done! I have installed RED and required add on using following below steps. It worked successfully with predefined keywords. Now I'm gonna create user defined keywords/libraries using the same editor. I don't know where to start up. Will it work creating just a java project? Should I need to include any additional libraries?

*Steps followed to proceed with RED:*

```
1. RED Version Conclusion: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/release.md
  2. RED Installation Instructions: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/installation.md
  3. ROBOT Framework prerequisites using RED: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/first_steps/download_install.html.md
  4. To verify Installations in Eclipse:  Help -> Installation Details to check if RED is visible on installed features list
  5. Create Project and Tests using RED in Eclipse: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/first_steps/create_run.html.md
  6. RED Steps: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/First_steps.md
  7. Quick STart: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/user_guide/quick_start.html.md
```

Comment: Extended the answer to included the answers to this question as well.